# Cisco 9200L has empty config after IOS update

Tags: cisco, ios-xe

I have uploaded the newest recommended image on a C9200L switch, and its running the new version now. But the config is empty. Do i need to copy the old config again or how do i recover the old config again?

Comment: If the configuration file is not in NVRAM, you've probably lost it.  You will have to use your backup (if you have one).

Comment: I can't see it on the cli when i connect via console but its still there when i check the web-cli. strange behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the configuration in the web interface has been saved/copied to the startup configuration storage on the flash memory of the switch. You may be seeing the switch configured in the web UI but it is not saved to the startup config so on command line when you look at the output of 'show configuration' you see nothing. Try 'show running configuration' on the command line or update this question with any error output when you try to view the config on command line/console.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest first delete your Web GUI cookies, than reload switch and try the Web GUI again.